# How Create table in power automate

Tags: power-automate

How Create table in power automate

file : give file path
Table Range : ''!A1:M1
table range should be according to no. of columns req. ex. A1 to M1 like 13 columns
Table Name : xyx
columns Name : ABC, POW, HYI

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use Office Scripts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

There's plenty of documentation so that should be enough for you to implement my answer but this link is the one that tells you how to do it in PowerAutomate ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration

This script (although short and crude) will do what you want.  If there's a gap, it's up to you to enhance it.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, sheetName: string, tableName: string, address: string) {
    let table = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName).addTable(address, true);
    table.setName(tableName);
}
```

If I run it over my workbook via PA ...

[image: PA]

... this is the before and after.

##### Before

[image: Before]

##### After

[image: After]